# SharePoint Enhanced Rich Text - Modifying Link Issue

Tags: rich-text

One of our user is using an "Enhanced Rich Text" column in a list in SharePoint 2010.

They are using "Insert Link --> From Address" button and adding a link. SharePoint is modifying the link and causing the trouble as the modified link is erroring out.

User is trying to add the link

> "http://********/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR%3Awt.part.WTPart%3A391494607&u8=1"

and SharePoint is changing it to

> "http://********/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=VR:wt.part.WTPart:391494607%26u8=1"

Can somebody help me find the reason for this and what could be done to add the link that doesn't error out?

I replaced the server name with * in the URL before /Windchill, for not wanting to expose the server name.

Answer (score 1):

The %3A is replaced by a colon, by means of decoding an URL. I noticed it even results in an error on my page if you include %20 (a space).

More information about [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

This encoding most likely happens as part of the "removing unsafe content" process. If you edit the source code in SharePoint Designer you get a message that the unsafe content will be removed. After this the %3A suddenly changed into a colon. The same thing no doubt happens when you save in the browser. AFAIK there's no way to change this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and responding Anima. I am a bit confused with what the system is doing here. If we try to understand that it is doing URL decoding by converting %3A to :, then why is the system also doing encoding by replacing & with %26 at the same time?

Comment: The encoding on itself does make sense, %26 would be resolved to & later on. Why it doesn't encode the colon again... I don't know. Maybe there's some security issue concerning %A3. But I doubt it.